# Implementing MVVMC and Dependency Injection

Tags: mvvm, dependency-injection

I have just read [this](http://skimp-blog.blogspot.com/2012/02/mvvm-is-dead-long-live-mvvmc.html) article about MVVMC pattern. Now I have a question. Should Controller be injected to ViewModel, or ViewModel should be injected into Controller?

Comment: Maybe I'm old fashioned, but do you really need this pattern?  I wasn't too impressed with the justification made by the author in the linked article.  It seemed to be programming for the "what if" instead of the "right now" which violates the YAGNI principle.  Some of the claims were a bit extreme too.  Any time you add yet another layer of abstraction (and this IS just the UI layer alone we are talking about), the complexity of the solution increases.  I'm just holding out for the day we have MVVMCMVPVMVC...to draw a control.

Comment: What about mess in a ViewModel code?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define "mess".  Do you have a specific problem you are solving with the addition of a Controller?

Comment: ...and I ask genuinely because I'm trying to understand too.

Comment: I mean - now I have one Panorama View in Windows Phone application. Every part of Panorma view has it's own list, which need one part of ViewModel. So I have now - 3 ObservableCollection. Next step is calling some services to get data to list. ViewModel complexity increased dramatically

Comment: But maybe you are right - adding additional layer would also increased complexity. In a fact, still I can use partial class in ViewModel.

Comment: @JordanParmer: There is no problem in software that can't be solved by adding a layer of abstraction. Well, expect the problem of too many layers of abstraction ofcourse :)

Comment: Although Jordan might convinced you otherwise, it is still an interesting question and it would be good for the community when this question is answered.

Comment: Actually, until there is no good answer - I will wait. For now, I have partial class. No problem to change.

Answer (score 9):

The MVVMC is simply a MVC where the View is replaced by a ViewModel pair.

- The View interacts ONLY with the ViewModel taking advantage of the powerful data binding mechanisms in XAML based technologies.
- The ViewModel can notify the Controller but SHOULD NEVER inject a controller.

I have put together a simply sample based on the well know sample of Josh Smith on MSDN... where I have introduced a Controller.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you are doing. I'm going to guess that most of the time the Controller would not need to be injected into either, but if it is needed, it is more likely to be needed in the ViewModel. Let me explain.

What are you doing with the controller? You must be doing something.. If that "something" is solely related to "what the data looks like", then it belongs in the View. If it is related to "what is be being shown to the user" then it belongs in the ViewModel.

I'm injecting a controller into one of my ViewModels. My ViewModel represents data which is then graphed in the View. I have a command which moves a data item from the current graph to a  new graph. Since this changes "what is being displayed in the graph window" I implemented the command in my ViewModel. The ViewModel removes the data item from its own collection of items, and then uses the Controller to request a new view be created for that new data (it already had this functionality).

Looking at the article, I don't see arrows between the controller and the view
[image: From the article you linked]

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel is a contract between the View and the Controller, and ideally does not need to know about (be dependent on) either.

So I definitely wouldn't be injecting a Controller into a ViewModel.

I'm not sure I'd be doing the opposite either: the controller is normally responsible for creating new ViewModel instances. If you want to go for a more loosely coupled implementation, you could go for injecting an abstract factory into the Controller, to avoid directly creating new instances of your ViewModel classes.

Comment: But when I will inject Controller into ViewModel it will be still MVVM pattern - in a fact. Controller has all logic, which is provided (in one Controller class) to View Model. There are many services injected into Controller. It is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Controller **should** be injected as an abstraction IController. The ViewModel needs IController to be able to navigate to a different View/ViewModel.

For example, in ViewModel:

```
IController _controller;

public MyViewModel(IController controller){
  _controller = controller;
}

void NavigateHome();
{
  _controller.NavigateHome();
}
```

The abstraction IController is better than injecting the Controller itself for these reasons:

1. Testability. You can inject a mock IController and test the ViewModel
2. Decoupling. ViewModel doesn't have to know Controller.

I developed a lightweight framework for doing MVVMC in WPF.
It has a lot of resemblance to MVC in Asp.NET Core.

Check it out if you're looking for a WPF solution.

Blog post with documentation:
http://michaelscodingspot.com/2017/02/15/wpf-page-navigation-like-mvc-part-2-mvvmc-framework/

GitHub:
https://github.com/michaelscodingspot/WPF_MVVMC